# Jest configuration in react native

Tags: react-native, unit-testing, jestjs, babel-jest

How to configure jest in react native . i know there is some dependency  for that. I  added all these dependency . Below i sharing all classes related to this

1. package.json
2. jest.config.json
3. babel.config.js

i Write a simple test case below i shared , When i run this i got many issue related npm  module , i don't know  proper reason. any one know how resolve that .
Below i  shared all the issue  those i get when run  the test

Some issues i  resolved but still issue i coming one by one i don't the proper reason  ,  this because of  configure, compatibility  or other thing  . Any one know the proper solution for this

```js
 1. import typeof AccessibilityInfo from './Libraries/Components/AccessibilityInfo/AccessibilityInfo';
    ^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

      2 |
      3 | import React from 'react';
    > 4 | import 'react-native';
        | ^
      5 | import loginScren from '../src/screens/login/index';
      6 |
      
      
      ====================================================
      
 2.   [@RNC/AsyncStorage]: NativeModule: AsyncStorage is null.

    To fix this issue try these steps:

      • Run `react-native link @react-native-async-storage/async-storage` in the project root.

      • Rebuild and restart the app.

      • Run the packager with `--reset-cache` flag.

      • If you are using CocoaPods on iOS, run `pod install` in the `ios` directory and then rebuild and re-run the app.

      • If this happens while testing with Jest, check out docs how to integrate AsyncStorage with it: https://react-native-async-storage.github.io/async-storage/docs/advanced/jest
      
      ==========================================
      
   3.   TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'config' of 'options' as it is undefined.
      
      ======================================
      
   4.   node_modules/@react-native/polyfills/error-guard.js:14
    type ErrorHandler = (error: mixed, isFatal: boolean) => void;
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier.    how to resolve this 
    
    ================================
    5. import {createStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/stack';
        | ^
      2 | import MyEquipment from '../../screens/myequipment';
      3 | import EquipmentSummary from '../../screens/myequipment/equipmentSummary';
      4 | import EquipmentDocumentation from '../../screens/myequipment/equipmentDocumentation';

      at Object.error (node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/lib/commonjs/RNGestureHandlerModule.ts:5:11)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/lib/commonjs/handlers/createHandler.ts:10:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/lib/commonjs/handlers/gestureHandlers.ts:7:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/lib/commonjs/index.ts:28:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/@react-navigation/stack/lib/commonjs/views/GestureHandlerNative.tsx:2:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/@react-navigation/stack/lib/commonjs/views/GestureHandler.ios.tsx:1:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/@react-navigation/stack/lib/commonjs/views/Stack/StackView.tsx:12:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/@react-navigation/stack/lib/commonjs/navigators/createStackNavigator.tsx:15:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/@react-navigation/stack/lib/commonjs/index.tsx:9:1)
      at Object.require (src/navigators/stacks/equipment.js:1:1)
      at Object.require (src/navigators/tab.js:4:1)
      at Object.require (src/navigators/drawer.js:3:1)
      at Object.require (src/root.js:6:1)
      at Object.require (App.js:7:1)
      at Object.require (src/actions/authenticate.js:16:1)
      at Object.require (src/screens/login/index.js:25:1)
      at Object.require (src/screens/login/__tests__/index.test.js:4:1)

 FAIL  src/screens/login/__tests__/index.test.js
```

```js
import React from 'react';
import {fireEvent,render} from '@testing-library/react-native';
import Login from '../index'



describe('LoginScreen', () => {
  it('should update email state when onChangeText is called', () => {
    const { getByTestId } = render(<Login/>);
    const emailInput = getByTestId('login-username');
    fireEvent.changeText(emailInput, 'test@example.com');
     expect(emailInput.props.value).toBe('test@example.com');
  });
});
```

```js
module.exports = {
  preset: 'react-native',
  moduleFileExtensions: ['js', 'jsx', 'json', 'ts', 'tsx'],
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.test.js$': 'babel-jest',
    '^.+\\.jsx$': 'babel-jest',
    '^.+\\.js$': 'babel-jest',
    '\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|webp)$': 'jest-transform-stub',
  },

  transformIgnorePatterns: [
    '/node_modules/(?!(@react-native*|react-native|one-weir-mobile|react-native-config|@react-navigation|rn-fetch-blob|@react-native-async-storage/async-storage|react-native-nfc-manager|react-native-gesture-handler)|/).*',
  ],
  setupFiles: [
    "./node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/jestSetup.js"
  ],
  testRegex: '(/__tests__/.*|(\\.|/)(test|spec))\\.(jsx?|tsx?)$',
  testPathIgnorePatterns: ['/node_modules/', '/dist/'],
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['@testing-library/jest-native/extend-expect'],
};
```

```js
module.exports = {
    presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],

};
```

```
  "name": "project name",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start --reset-cache",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.15.8",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.11",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "^6.0.0",
    "@react-native-community/progress-bar-android": "^1.0.4",
    "@react-native-community/progress-view": "^1.3.1",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.11.11",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^5.12.5",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.9.8",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.14.5",
    "@testing-library/jest-native": "^5.4.2",
    "appcenter": "4.4.5",
    "appcenter-analytics": "4.4.5",
    "appcenter-crashes": "4.4.5",
    "axios": "^0.21.2",
    "base-64": "^1.0.0",
    "jail-monkey": "^2.7.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "one-weir-mobile": "git+https://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:x-oauth-basic@github.com/weirgroup/one_weir_mobile.git#integration",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "puppeteer": "^10.1.0",
    "react": "17.0.1",
    "react-native": "0.64.4",
    "react-native-app-auth": "^6.4.0",
    "react-native-circular-progress": "^1.3.7",
    "react-native-config": "^1.4.3",
    "react-native-crypto-js": "^1.0.0",
    "react-native-date-picker": "^4.0.0",
    "react-native-device-info": "^8.1.4",
    "react-native-elements": "^3.4.2",
    "react-native-exception-handler": "^2.10.10",
    "react-native-fs": "^2.19.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.10.3",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^4.8.4",
    "react-native-ionicons": "^4.6.5",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.9.5",
    "react-native-mail": "^6.1.1",
    "react-native-maps": "^0.27.1",
    "react-native-nfc-manager": "^3.11.0",
    "react-native-pdf": "^6.3.0",
    "react-native-progress": "^5.0.0",
    "react-native-progress-circle": "^2.1.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^2.2.4",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.3.2",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.4.0",
    "react-native-svg": "^12.1.1",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^8.1.0",
    "react-navigation": "^4.4.4",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.4",
    "redux": "^4.1.1",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "rn-fetch-blob": "^0.12.0",
    "typescript": "^4.3.5"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "@jest/create-cache-key-function": "^27.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.14.6",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.22.5",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.22.5",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.14.6",
    "@react-native-community/clipboard": "^1.5.1",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^3.0.0",
    "@testing-library/react-native": "^12.1.2",
    "@types/jest": "^29.5.0",
    "@types/react-native": "^0.72.2",
    "babel-jest": "^27.5.1",
    "eslint": "^7.31.0",
    "eslint-plugin-eslint-comments": "^3.2.0",
    "jest": "^29.5.0",
    "jest-transform-stub": "^2.0.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.66.1",
    "react-native-mock": "^0.3.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "^17.0.1"
  }
}
```